# Python typing how to apply ABC or Protocol to multiple mixins

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to extend a certain class, called a `ModelSerializer` from Django Rest Framework, but the exact class in not important.

The following example code is to illustrates what I am trying to do. The actual code is too large for it to be meaningful here.

I am adding lots of functionlity so I broke the extra functionality down into 3 mixins:

- `ConstraintsMixin` - It uses a `Constraints` dataclass
- `FooMixin`
- `AnotherMixin`

Then I created an `ABC` with the methods/attributes that derived classes must implement called:

- `ThingsToImplmement`

The reason I use an `ABC` and not a protocol, is from my research I wish to show errors/linting at the implementation of `MyBaseSerializer` (explained below), whereas a protocol would only lint errors at consumption of `MyBaseSerializer`, which would be hidden behind `Django Rest Framework` generic views, but am willing to a `Protocol` if they are more appropriate.

I then tied all the mixins together with the `ThingsToImplement` abstract class, along with the `rest_framework.ModelSerializer` class into a base class called:

- `MyBaseSerializer`

i.e.:

```
class MyBaseSerializer(ConstrainsMixin, FooMixin, AnotherMixin, ThingsToImplement, ModelSerializer):
```

Now I am trying to add type hints so when a class/mixin refers to attributes/method of another mixin/class/ModelSerializer, it does not show linting errors. Below is with a protocol `MySerializerProtocol` which I feel should not be needed, because it pretty much duplicates `ThingsToImplement`. The linting errors I get with `pyright` are shown as comments. How would one arrange the following code in terms of ABC's or Protocols to pass linting, and reveal implementation errors when one implements the `AbstractSerializer` class? (not some code behind the scenes from `Django Rest Framework` will instantiate the implemented `AbstractSerializer`).

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union, Protocol
from dataclasses import dataclass
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


@dataclass
class Constraints:
    width: int
    height: int

class ThingsToImplement(ABC):
    my_number: int
    constraints: Constraints

    @abstractmethod
    def get_da_name(self, s:str) -> str:
        pass

class MySerializerProtocol(Protocol):
    constraints: Constraints
    my_number: int

    def get_da_name(self) -> str:
        ...

class ConstraintsMixin:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'constraints'):
            raise NotImplementedError('Please add a constraints attribute')

    @classmethod
    def print_constraints(cls:MySerializerProtocol) -> None:
        print(cls.constraints.width, cls.constraints.height)


class FooMixin:
    def get_foo(self:MySerializerProtocol) -> str:
        return self.get_da_name() if self.constraints.width > 123 else 'Too small to be named'

    def get_bar(self: Union[MySerializerProtocol, ModelSerializer]) -> str:  # Type of parameter "self" must be a supertype of its class "FooMixin"
        # self.to_representation and self.instance are from Model Serializer
        return self.to_representation(self.instance)  # Cannot access member "to_representation" for type "MySerializerProtocol". Member "to_representation" is unknown

    def from_another(self):
        return f"from {self.get_number()}"  # Cannot access member "get_number" for type "FooMixin". Member "get_number" is unknown.

class AnotherMixin:
    def get_number(self:MySerializerProtocol) -> int:
        return self.my_number

    def from_foo(self):
        return "from " + self.get_foo()  # Cannot access member "get_foo" for type "AnotherMixin". Member "get_foo" is unknown.


class AbstractSerializer(ConstraintsMixin, FooMixin, AnotherMixin, ThingsToImplement, ModelSerializer): # The metaclass of a derived class must be a subclass of the metaclasses of all its base classes
    def implemented_method_1(self):
        return 1

    def implemented_method_2(self):
        return 2

    # ...
    def implemented_method_30(self):
        return 30


class MySerializer(AbstractSerializer):
    my_number = 7
    constraints = Constraints(1, 2)

    def get_da_name(self, s):
        self.number += 1  # Cannot access member "number" for type "MySerializer". Member "number" is unknown.
        return 'hi ' + s
```

Comment: `get_da_name` has a non-optional parameter `s` on `ThingsToImplement` and is implemented accordingly in `MySerializer`. Yet the same method has _no_ parameter `s` on `MySerializerProtocol` and is called without one in `FooMixin.get_foo`. Please clarify which one is the correct signature.

Comment: Question 2: Could it be that you meant `self.my_number += 1` in `MySerializer.get_da_name` instead of `self.number += 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you showed. I tried to go through those that I thought were most pressing in no particular order.

### Avoid nested ABCs if possible

Since `AbstractSerializer` will be the abstract base class for your custom serializers, I would suggest defining the abstract methods like `get_da_name` on that class directly instead of having them in another, separate ABC like `ThingsToImplement`.

It makes the intent clearer because users of that `AbstractSerializer` will look at it and immediately see the work they will have to do.

The attributes that need to be present on every serializer subclass like `constraints` don't technically need to be declared on the ABC, but I think it makes sense for the same reason.

### The purpose of `Protocol`s

I would argue that the one of the [main purposes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) of `Protocol` is to simplify doing exactly the things you are doing here. You define common behavior in a protocol that static type checkers can assume is available on a variable annotated with that `Protocol`.

In your specific case, it is up to you how finely grained your `Protocol` subclasses should be. If you want to be very pedantic, any Mix-in can have its own corresponding `Protocol`, but I would argue that is overkill most of the time. It really depends on how complex that "common behavior" becomes, which the `Protocol` is supposed to encapsulate.

In your example code I would only define one `Protocol`. (see below)

In addition, `Protocol` can be used in a [generic](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#generic-protocols) way, which IMHO fits perfectly into the model serializer context since every serializer will have his `instance` set as can be seen in the type stubs for [`ModelSerializer`](https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs/blob/1.7.0/rest_framework-stubs/serializers.pyi#L215) (inheriting from `BaseSerializer`), which is also generic over a `Model`-bound [type variable](https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs/blob/1.7.0/rest_framework-stubs/serializers.pyi#L90).

### Allow ABCs to inherit from `ConstraintsMixin`

Since you set up your `__init_subclass__` class method on `ConstraintsMixin` so strictly, you need to ensure that the actual ABC you want to create (i.e. `AbstractSerializer`) can inherit from it without triggering the error.

For this you simply add the [`ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) check to `__init_subclass__` first and avoid triggering the error on ABCs.

### Use `MySerializerProtocol` in Mix-ins

Since your Mix-ins assume certain behavior in their instance methods, that is exactly where you can use `MySerializerProtocol` to annotate the `self` parameter.

Again, you may consider splitting the `Protocol` up further, if it gets too complex.

### Solve the Metaclass conflict

Luckily, this is very easy in this case, since there are only two non-`type` Metaclasses involved here, namely the [`SerializerMetaclass`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.14.0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L278) from Django REST Framework and the [`ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) from `abc`, and they don't *actually* conflict as far as I can see. You just need to define your own Metaclass that inherits from both and specify it in your serializer ABC.

### Specify Django Model in subclasses

If you go the generic route (which seems more consistent to me), you should specify the concrete Django Model handled by the serializer, when you subclass `AbstractSerializer`.

If you *don't* want to go that route, `mypy` will complain in `--strict` mode upon subclassing `ModelSerializer` (that it is missing a type argument), but you can silence that. Also, you can omit the `[M]` everywhere in the code (see below) and instead just declare `instance: Model` on `MySerializerProtocol`.

### Fully annotated example code

```py
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar

from django.db.models import Model
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, SerializerMetaclass


M = TypeVar("M", bound=Model)


# Placeholder for a model to be imported from another module:
class ConcreteDjangoModel(Model):
    pass


@dataclass
class Constraints:
    width: int
    height: int


class MySerializerProtocol(Protocol[M]):
    """For type annotations only; generic over `M` like `ModelSerializer`"""
    my_number: int
    constraints: Constraints
    # From ModelSerializer:
    instance: M

    # From AbstractSerializer:
    def get_da_name(self, s: str) -> str: ...
    # From FooMixin:
    def get_foo(self) -> str: ...
    # From AnotherMixin:
    def get_number(self) -> int: ...
    # From ModelSerializer:
    def to_representation(self, instance: M) -> Any: ...


class ConstraintsMixin:
    # Class attributes that must be set by subclasses:
    constraints: Constraints

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        if not isinstance(cls, ABCMeta) and not hasattr(cls, "constraints"):
            raise NotImplementedError("Please add a constraints attribute")
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def print_constraints(cls: type[MySerializerProtocol[M]]) -> None:
        print(cls.constraints.width, cls.constraints.height)


class FooMixin:
    def get_foo(self: MySerializerProtocol[M]) -> str:
        s = "something"
        return self.get_da_name(s) if self.constraints.width > 123 else "Too small to be named"

    def get_bar(self: MySerializerProtocol[M]) -> Any:
        return self.to_representation(self.instance)

    def from_another(self: MySerializerProtocol[M]) -> str:
        return f"from {self.get_number()}"


class AnotherMixin:
    def get_number(self: MySerializerProtocol[M]) -> int:
        return self.my_number

    def from_foo(self: MySerializerProtocol[M]) -> str:
        return f"from {self.get_foo()}"


class AbstractSerializerMeta(SerializerMetaclass, ABCMeta):
    """To avoid metaclass conflicts in `AbstractSerializer`"""
    pass


class AbstractSerializer(
    ABC,
    ConstraintsMixin,
    FooMixin,
    AnotherMixin,
    ModelSerializer[M],
    metaclass=AbstractSerializerMeta,
):
    # Class attributes that must be set by subclasses:
    constraints: Constraints

    @abstractmethod
    def get_da_name(self, s: str) -> str: ...


class MySerializer(AbstractSerializer[ConcreteDjangoModel]):
    my_number: int = 7
    constraints: Constraints = Constraints(1, 2)

    def get_da_name(self, s: str) -> str:
        self.my_number += 1
        return f"hi {s}"
```

If you have an older Python version (below `3.9` I think), you may need to replace `type[MySerializerProtocol[M]]` with `typing.Type[MySerializerProtocol[M]]` in the `print_constraints` method.

---

Thanks for the fun little exercise. Hope this helps.

Feel free to comment, if something is unclear. I will try to amend my answer if necessary.

Comment: Wow thanks for so much insight. The reason I separated out the class `ThingsToImplement` is because there are a lot of implemented methods in the `AbstractSerializer`, so my thinking was make it clear what is required to be implemented by separating it (instead of one huge mega class with lots of methods). Do you think my point is valid or do you still thing its better to combine the abstract classes? (I updated the example to `implemented_method_1` to `implemented_method_30` in `AbstractSerializer`

Comment: @run_the_race Glad I could help. It depends. Maybe it makes sense to separate it. I would probably try and separate out the non-abstract methods as much as possible and have `AbstractSerializer` define _only_ all the abstract methods. But again, this is a matter of preference and consideration for readability, usability etc. You may well be right to factor it out the way you did. As long as you consider the things I pointed out, I am sure it'll be fine. Either way, this will not change the relevance of the `Protocol` for annotating the Mix-ins in my opinion.

Comment: @run_the_race Sure. I actually linked that part of the documentation referring to generic protocols in my original answer. But they barely explain it there. That topic is a little too complex to cover in a comment and goes beyond the scope of the question, but maybe I'll create a question-answer on that topic, unless I find an existing one explaining the subtleties. Very briefly: You associate _some_ type (or multiple) with the protocol so that you can construct e.g. functions that are generic over a generic protocol and its associated type(s).

Comment: @danill Sorry my question was premature, I was working my way linearly through your answer, but did come across it later on. That documentation is adueqate thank you! Its like C++ templates, cheers! Thanks again this is a big help. I was going around in confusion circles the whole of saturday, thank you!